# Alphabetizing words in java

Tags: java, string

Here is my program and I am not sure what is wrong with it. If I delete the Alphabetizing method it works totally fine, can someone tell me what is wrong with this method and how to fix it. The first part I am supposed to print the words as they appear, the second part I am supposed to Capitalize them, then the third part I am supposed to add a hyphen and remove the space between the words and finally the last part I am supposed to alphabetize them.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class WordFun {

    private String word, loc, changedWord;

    public WordFun() {
    }

    public WordFun(String w) {
        word = w;
        changedWord = w;
    }

    public void setWord(String w) {
    }

    public void makeUpper() {
        changedWord = word.toUpperCase();
    }

    public void addHyphen() {
        String hyphen = word.trim();
        changedWord = word.replaceAll(" ", "-");
    }

    public void alphabetize() {
        int loc;
        loc = original.indexOf(" ");
        String wordOne = original.substring(0, loc);
        String wordTwo = original.substring(loc + 1, word.length());
        if (wordOne.compareTo(wordTwo) > 0) {
            word = wordTwo + " " + wordOne;
        } else {
            word = wordOne + " " + wordTwo;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return changedWord;
    }
}
```

Here is the runner program

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class WordFunRunner {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        WordFun test = new WordFun("Hello World");
        out.println(test);
        test.makeUpper();
        out.println(test);
        test.addHyphen();
        out.println(test);
        test.alphabetize();
        out.println(test);

//add more test cases
        WordFun test1 = new WordFun("Jeroo Bob");
        out.println(test1);
        test1.makeUpper();
        out.println(test1);
        test1.addHyphen();
        out.println(test1);
        test1.alphabetize();
        out.println(test1);

        WordFun test2 = new WordFun("Computer Science");
        out.println(test2);
        test2.makeUpper();
        out.println(test2);
        test2.addHyphen();
        out.println(test2);
        test2.alphabetize();
        out.println(test2);

        WordFun test3 = new WordFun("Golden Bears");
        out.println(test3);
        test3.makeUpper();
        out.println(test3);
        test3.addHyphen();
        out.println(test3);
        test3.alphabetize();
        out.println(test3);

        WordFun test4 = new WordFun("Upper Arlington");
        out.println(test4);
        test4.makeUpper();
        out.println(test4);
        test4.addHyphen();
        out.println(test4);
        test4.alphabetize();
        out.println(test4);
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `word = ` with `changedWord = ` and `original` with `word`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute `original` is missing in your `alphabetize()` method

refer below code.

```
public void alphabetize() {
    int loc;
    loc = word.indexOf(" ");
    String wordOne = word.substring(0, loc);
    String wordTwo = word.substring(loc + 1, word.length());
    if (wordOne.compareTo(wordTwo) > 0) {
        changedWord = wordTwo + " " + wordOne;
    } else {
        changedWord = wordOne + " " + wordTwo;
    }
}
```